# Android - what is the good-practice way of handling button clicks on the header of an app

Tags: android

I am working on a header for an app.  The header will have 4 buttons.  Each button will have a listener and some code to send it to the home of that button.

The Java code for the buttons will be the same so I am wondering what I can do so that I can have that code in one place and reuse it in all my screens. How do people typically handle this kind of a scenario? Should/can I make a utility class and just import that? If I do, then how do I handle code like this so it would know which intent I am on?

```
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
          CurrActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Thanks!

Comment: you manage to develop an action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options I can think of:-

- Have an ActivityBase class or a FragmentBase class that you put all your navigation logic into, all your activities/fragments would subclass from this, therefore share the same nav logic
- Create a custom view based of LinearLayout or ViewGroup, treat each child view of this custom view as a navigation item, this might be a bit heavy depending on your experience but definetly the way I would do it these days, info here on custom views http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

With both options you should look at the **include** tag that will allow you to share the xml that defines your navigation across layouts.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm for what I understand an action bar might help you?

I suggest you to check one of good implemantations of action bar. (open source)

> ActionBarSherlock ActionBarSherlock is an standalone library designed
>   to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all
>   versions of Android through a single API.
>
> The library will automatically use the native ActionBar implementation
>   on Android 4.0 or later. For previous versions which do not include
>   ActionBar, a custom action bar implementation based on the sources of
>   Ice Cream Sandwich will automatically be wrapped around the layout.
>   This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar
>   for every version of Android from 2.x and up.
>
> See http://actionbarsherlock.com for more information.

Comment: I think I can agree here that action bar tabs could be of use